# Peut-on omettre l'article entre une préposition et un nom, et si oui quand ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, déterminants

Quand ne doit-on pas utiliser l'article (défini ou indéfini) devant un nom?

1. Par exemple on dit « avec douceur » mais « sans l'agressivité ».
2. Un autre exemple : « sur fond rouge » ou « sur un/le fond rouge ».

Comment: En fait, non, c'est « sans agressivité » sauf contexte inhabituel.

Comment: Roman Valeri a fort bien fait ressortir les points communs et les divergences de « avec douceur »  vs « avec la douceur ». SVP, pourrait-on le faire à propos de « sans agressivité » et « sans l'agressivité » (dans des contextes inhabituels à quoi Gilles s'est reporté dans son commentaire ci-devant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il serait plus facile de comparer ces expressions sans faire varier le nom pris en exemple, car il introduit la fausse impression que la distinction peut être liée au terme choisi.

On peut en effet aussi bien rencontrer les expressions *avec douceur* et *avec la douceur*, qui sont toutes deux correctes mais ont des usages différents.

- *Avec douceur* est une forme contractée qui a le même sens que *avec (de la) douceur*. Cette expression est complète et peut servir telle quelle dans un sens adverbial.

  Exemple:

  > Le médecin m'a examiné **avec douceur**, ça n'a pas été douloureux.
- *Avec la douceur* n'est pas une expression complète valide (hors contexte vraiment très spécifique éventuellement?!), mais pourrait se retrouver dans une expression plus longue ou on qualifierait cette douceur (il faut bien justifier l'emploi de l'article défini).

  Exemple :

  > **Avec la douceur** qu'on lui connait, le médecin m'a examiné.

  ou

  > La violence de la révélation qu'il me fit contrastait fortement **avec la douceur** des soins qu'il m'avait prodigué.

Si l'on disait seulement *Le médecin m'a examiné avec la douceur*, une confusion naitrait de la présence de l'article indéfini, et un interlocuteur pourrait répondre à juste titre *...de quelle douceur parle-t-on ici?* ou simplement *...quelle douceur?*

Comment: +1 d'avoir bien fait ressortir les points communs et les divergences de « avec douceur » vs « avec la douceur ».

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit d'un problème de contexte :

> Agir avec *douceur* ou *agressivité*, signifie un comportement de la
> personne.
>
> Utiliser *la douceur* ou *l'agressivité* pour arriver à un but, indique le
> choix d'une tactique, de la méthode employée.

---

***Complément***

Utiliser un nom ou son antonyme est un choix subjectif, et dépend du contexte ou de l’agent,

> — contexte normal : *l’infirmière agit avec douceur avec les patients*.
>
> — comportement exceptionnel : *l’intervention des soldats a été réalisée sans agressivité*.