# Quand utiliser « sans + nom » ou « sans + article défini ou indéfini + nom » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, déterminants

Je souhaite me renseigner sur la différence entre **sans + nom** et **sans + l'article défini/indéfini + nom**. J'ai trouvé un [commentaire de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/peut-on-omettre-larticle-devant-un-nom-et-si-oui-quand), dans lequel il met en avant que **sans + l'article défini + nom** ne figure que dans des contextes inhabituels. Lesquels ?

L'OP a posé une question dans laquelle le nom est « agressivité », mais je voudrais généraliser sa question à tous les noms.

Comment: La question précédente était déjà générale, bien que les réponses actuelles ne le soient pas. À moins que tu n'aies une objection, je vais considérer cette question comme un doublon et lancer un bounty sur l'autre question.

Comment: Réponse courte à ta question dans le cas de la préposition *sans* : pour une fois c'est comme en anglais, en espérant que ça aide :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Aucune objection. Je guetterai l'autre question.